# Motivation for studying rational curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Why do we study rational curves?

A curve $f(x,y)=0$ is called a rational curve if there exists two rational functions $\chi(t)$ and $\psi(t)$ such that $f(\chi(t),\psi(t))=0$ for all $t$.

Why is it not sufficient to study polynomials?

I read somewhere that we want to study conic sections but conic sections are not covered by polynomials. I do not really know what this means. Please enlighten me about this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful but one possible reason is that rational curves are birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$, and varieties with many rational curves have good deformation properties.

Comment: I do not know what is birational... i do not know what are deformation properties.. @DerekAllums. Please suggest where can i have a look at what you have said

Comment: It may be helpful to let everyone know what your background is then.

Comment: I am just a beginner... I just only know the definition and some examples of rational curves.. i know that $y^2=x^2+x^3$ is a rational curve..

Comment: Dear kk lm, don't worry: rational curves are beginners stuff, despite the efforts of some books and people to hide that fact :-) I'll show that below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) The curve  $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$ (our friend the good old circle!) is a rational curve since it can be parametrized as $$x=\frac {t^2-1}{t^2+1} \quad ,\quad y=\frac {2t}{t^2+1}$$ 2) This is interesting because it allows one to find points on a circle with rational coordinates by plugging in rational numbers for $t$.
Equivalently it allows us to find right-angled triangles with integral sides.
For example: choosing $t=6$ we get $x=\frac {35}{37}, y= \frac {12}{37}$ so that $(\frac {35}{37})^2+(\frac {12}{37})^2=1$ and we get a right angle triangle with sides $35,12,37$ satisfying Pythagoras' relation $35^2+12^2=37^2$.
Amazingly,  the Babylonians somehow knew about this [about 3800 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimpton_322).

3)  However it is impossible to find two polynomials (at least one of them non-constant)  $x=P(t), y=Q(t)$ satisfying $P^2(t)+Q^2(t)=1$.
Why? For example because the the limit of $P^2(t)+Q^2(t)$ for $t$ tending to infinity is infinity.

4) So, yes, we need rational functions and not just polynomials  to define rational curves: mathematical terminology is sometimes pleasantly logical (or should I say rational ?)

Comment: I think i got it but What are rectangular triangles?

Comment: @kklm: See [right-angled triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-angled_triangle) (in some languages, they're called rectangular triangles).

Comment: @Remy : Thanks Thanks..

Comment: I do not know whether to accept this answer or not.. I think this is sufficient... I do not know what to ask more...

Comment: Thanks, @Remy: I have changed my gallicism *rectangular triangle* to *right angled triangle* in my answer. Although almost everything I read in the professional mathematical literature is in English, I don't know the English terminology of elementary mathematics so well, since as a child  everything I read or heard was of course in French. For example  I only recently learned the complicated word *protractor*  :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : Can you please give some good reference to learn this rational curves...

Comment: [Shafarevich, Basic Algebraic Geometry, Volume 1](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Algebraic-Geometry-Varieties-Projective/dp/3540548122) pages 4,5,9,171,174. By the way, *every* page of that book is worth reading!